# Access hostname/port number to invoke ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using an ajax request to retrun json from a URL.

This is working locally as below :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/updates.json",      
            type: 'post',
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(jsonResponse) {  
            }); 

            },
            error: function (err) {
            } 

        });
```

The url needs to be updated so that it works no matter the na eof server its deployed on.

Can url be replaced with something like :  "http://"+getThisHostName()+":8080/updates.json" ?

Is there a safe way of returning  the current hostname path ?

Comment: Just use a relative URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
//say you are on http://domain.com:8080
//this will request from http://domain.com:8080/updates.json
$.ajax({
    url: "/updates.json", 
    ...
});
```